# UDP multicasting. C#

Tags: c#, sockets, udp, multicast

I try to send message to all members of the group. Sender:

```
// Create socket
        Socket s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);

        // Multicast IP-address
        IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse("224.168.55.25");

        // Join multicast group
        s.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.AddMembership, new MulticastOption(ip));

        // TTL
        s.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.MulticastTimeToLive, 2);

        // Create an endpoint
        IPEndPoint ipep = new IPEndPoint(ip, 4567);

        // Connect to the endpoint
        s.Connect(ipep);

        // Scan message
         while (true)
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            string msg = Console.ReadLine();
            buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg);
            s.Send(buffer, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None);
            if (msg.Equals("Bye!", StringComparison.Ordinal))
                break;
        }

        // Close socket
        s.Close();
```

Receiver:

```
// Create new socket
        Socket s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);

        // Create IP endpoint
        IPEndPoint ipep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 4567);

        // Bind endpoint to the socket
        s.Bind(ipep);

        // Multicast IP-address
        IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse("224.168.55.25");

        // Add socket to the multicast group
        s.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.AddMembership, new MulticastOption(ip, IPAddress.Any));

        // Receive messages
        while (true)
        {
            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
            s.Receive(data);
            string str = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, data.Length);
            Console.WriteLine(str.Trim());
            if (str.Equals("Bye!", StringComparison.Ordinal))
            {
                break;
            }
        }
```

I don't uderstand why there is a lot of free space between messages when I print them to screen on the client side? Why loop in the `Receiver` program doesn't stop after receiveing message `Bye!`? How can I fix this problems?

Thank you very much!

Comment: What inside your receiver would cause your receiver to exit the loop? This doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Daniel Kelley, when loop breaks on the sender it is written in console: 'Press any key to continue...' So, the loop on the client side doesn't break because it is stil listening

Comment: Well, now you've edited your code it is clear where it is supposed to break.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a udp socket. Udp sockets are not connection oriented. So it just receives messages and has no idea about the state of the sender. Even if the sender socket closes, the receiver would keep on listening.
I hope I have understood your question correctly.

```
if (strData.Trim().Equals("Bye!", StringComparison.Ordinal))
{
                Console.WriteLine("that's right");
                break;
}
```

Comment: I want to send messages from server until comes message 'Bye!'. Receiver doesn't break the loop after receiving message 'Bye!'. I don't understand why...

Comment: I have not compiled the code but I think the code in my answer edit should work... or am I missing the point?

Comment: no, it doesn't help. I edited my code. Also I don't know why after every received message there are a lot of spaces written in console? How can I print only sended messages?

Comment: @user3649515 The receiver loop doesn't even have a *break* in it so how is it supposed to ever break?

Comment: well it wasn't when I commented. Also you need to evaluate the return value of the Socket.Receive method to learn how many bytes were actually read. You can't just pass data.Length to System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString because that will always be 1024.

Answer (score 1):

Socket.Receive() return the bytes received you should use the return value to generate the string, or you will get a string with the length of 1024 and Trim cannot handle it.

```
int len = s.Receive(data);
string str = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, len);
```

Comment: You can visit https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.receive?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Net_Sockets_Socket_Receive_System_Byte___