# C# - cannot receive UDP multicast frames

Tags: c#, multicast

I used the example from old question ([UDP multicasting. C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23846116/udp-multicasting-c-sharp)) to implement simple receiver/transmitter of MC packets.

## The receiver

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;


namespace multiCastRecv
{

    class recv
    {

        recv(string mcastGroup, string port)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Receive MC from group: {0}, Port: {1}", mcastGroup, port);
            // Create new socket
            Socket s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);

            // Create IP endpoint
            IPEndPoint ipep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, int.Parse(port));

            // Bind endpoint to the socket
            s.Bind(ipep);

            // Multicast IP-address
            IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse(mcastGroup);

            // Add socket to the multicast group
            s.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.AddMembership, new MulticastOption(ip, IPAddress.Any));

            // Receive messages
            while (true)
            {
                byte[] data = new byte[1024];
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting....");
                int len = s.Receive(data);
                Console.WriteLine("Rcv {0} bytes", len);
                string str = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, len);
                Console.WriteLine(str.Trim());
            }
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new recv("224.168.55.25", "4567");
        }
    }
}
```

## The transmitter:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;

namespace multiCastSend
{
    class send
    {
        send(string mcastGroup, string port, string ttl, string rep)
        {
            try
            {
                // Create socket
                Socket s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);

                // Multicast IP-address
                IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse(mcastGroup);

                // Join multicast group
                s.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.AddMembership, new MulticastOption(ip));

                // TTL
                s.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.MulticastTimeToLive, int.Parse(ttl));

                // Create an endpoint
                IPEndPoint ipep = new IPEndPoint(ip, int.Parse(port));

                // Connect to the endpoint
                s.Connect(ipep);

                // Scan message
                while (true)
                {
                    byte[] b = new byte[10];
                    for (int x = 0; x < b.Length; x++) b[x] = (byte)(x + 65);
                    for (int x = 0; x < int.Parse(rep); x++)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Sending ABCDEFGHIJ...");
                        s.Send(b, b.Length, SocketFlags.None);
                    }
                    Thread.Sleep(1000); // 1000 milliseconds i.e 1sec
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception e) { Console.Error.WriteLine(e.Message); }
        }
 
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            new send("224.168.55.25", "4567", "1", "2");
        }
    }
}
```

Both desktop and laptop were connected to the same simple HUB.
By running Wireshark in the receiver platform, I can see the MC packets correctly (see below), but the program didn't receive:

Frame 31355: 60 bytes on wire (480 bits), 60 bytes captured (480 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: Flextron_60:22:1f (00:21:cc:60:22:1f), Dst: IPv4mcast_28:37:19 (01:00:5e:28:37:19)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 10.13.2.165, Dst: 224.168.55.25
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 56556, Dst Port: 4567
Data (10 bytes)
Data: 4142434445464748494a
[Length: 10]

When I run the receiver and the transmitter in the same machine, it works.

Do someone has any idea?

Comment: Do the machines have multiple active network interfaces?  If so, the receiver should specify the interface to join the multicast group on, and the sender should set the option to set the outgoing interface for multicast.

Comment: @dbush - My desktop also includes VirtualBox network interface. When I disabled it the receiver worked.
Thanks a lot for your advice

Comment: As @dbush wrote, I found an example related to C# MulticastOption class in the following link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.multicastoption?view=net-5.0 . It is written there: "In both cases you must specify the local IPAddress to use." - means that for receiver and transmitter you need to specify the interface.